# Bamboo Deployment Fields

Tags: devops, bamboo, release-management

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a new field in the deployment screen for Bamboo. For example, I would like to add a field called "Release Notes" that I can use as a bamboo variable and replace in a custom NuGet package. 
[image: Custom Fields/Variables in Bamboo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that I know of in Bamboo, but one of the benefits of using Bamboo is its integration with the rest of the Atlasssian suite! Linking release notes in [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) or tickets in [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) to a specific deployment/build or in Bamboo is easy and incredibly robust.

Comment: Can those be pulled somehow into a Bamboo variable? The goal is transferring them into a NuGet package information, or at least entering them in somewhere so it can be token replaced into the XML file.

Comment: I see what you mean. You could, but it would be cumbersome.... You can use a deployment variable, but you are probably going to be using more text than for a typical variable. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/variables-for-deployment-environments-342754180.html

Your other option could be to store the release notes somewhere (maybe Confluence?) and have the deployment variable specify the location of the release notes.